# JAXB: package.package.<Type> is alrready define in package.package.<Type>.<Type>

Tags: java, xml, xpath, xsd, jaxb

I am trying to generate java classes from XSDs with JAXB.

The XSDs are official xsds in my company so I cannot modify them just for my project.
After hundreads of try and search on thi site I decided to ask the question directly.

I have this in my XSD:

```
<xs:element name="Line" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="999">
                                                    <xs:complexType>
                                                        <xs:sequence>
                                                            <xs:element name="Line" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="999">
                                                                <xs:complexType>
                                                                    <xs:attribute name="reference" type="xs:toto" use="optional">
                                                                    </xs:attribute>
                                                                </xs:complexType>
                                                            </xs:element>
                                                        </xs:sequence>
                                                        <xs:attribute name="reference" type="xs:toto" use="optional">

                                                        </xs:attribute>
                                                    </xs:complexType>
                                                </xs:element>
```

It result in issue:
**package.Index.Line is already defined in package.Index**

After looking at the generated code I can see that we have a static iner Class Line into another static inner class Line (under another Index)

I get error on the Line (at the top bottom)
**The nested type Line cannot hide an enclosing type**

If the name change (either on xsd or on java class after generation) I don' t have issue anymore.

I tried to create a binding file:

```
<jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="file:../path/myschema.xsd" node="//xs:element[@name='Index']">
    <jaxb:bindings node=".//xs:element[@name='Line']" multiple="true">
        <jaxb:property name="Lines"/>
    </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

I have the same issue... Because in fact under Index I have two nodes Line so I try with this:

```
<jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="file:path/myxsd.xsd" node="//xs:element[@name='Index']/xs:element[@name='Line']">
    <jaxb:bindings node="//xs:element[@name='Line']" multiple="true">
        <jaxb:property name="Lines"/>
    </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

or

```
<jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="file:path/myxsd.xsd" node="//xs:element[@name='Index']">
    <jaxb:bindings node="//xs:element[@name='Line']/xs:element[@name='Line']" multiple="true">
        <jaxb:property name="Lines"/>
    </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

But I get an generation issue:
com.sun.istack.SAXParseException2: XPath evaluation of "//xs:element[@name='Index']/xs:element[@name='Line']" results in empty target node

I am completely lost. I am eating nutella all day long to compensate the sadness I feel T_T

If you have suggestions ;)

Thanks in advance

Geoffrey

Comment: Line is inside `xs:complexType`. not under `xs:element` Line

Comment: So how will you do this?
This is not working
`<jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="file:file.xsd" node="//xs:element[@name='Line']/xs:complexType">
  <jaxb:bindings node="//xs:element[@name='Line']" multiple="true">
   <jaxb:property name="Lines"/>
  </jaxb:bindings>
 </jaxb:bindings>`

Comment: see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

First configure bindings to generate them as individual classes.

```
<jaxb:globalBindings localScoping="toplevel"/>
```

Then, use complete `XPath` for the referenced elements like below.

```
<bindings version="2.1" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <globalBindings localScoping="toplevel"/>

    <bindings schemaLocation="yourschema.xsd">
            <bindings node="//xs:element[@name='Index']/xs:complexType/xs:sequence/xs:element[@name='Line']/xs:complexType">
                <class name="Lines1"/>
            </bindings>
    </bindings>

        <bindings schemaLocation="yourschema.xsd">
                <bindings node="//xs:element[@name='Index']/xs:complexType/xs:sequence/xs:element[@name='Line']/xs:complexType/xs:sequence/xs:element[@name='Line']/xs:complexType">
                    <class name="Lines2"/>
                </bindings>
    </bindings>

</bindings>
```